# How do I recreate a SolrCloud shard using a compositeId router and known hash range?

Tags: solr, sharding, solrcloud

We have a SolrCloud setup with 20 shards, each with only 1 replica, served on 8 servers.

After a server went down we are left with 16 shards, which means that some of the compositeId hash ranges aren't hosted by any cores.  Somehow the shards/cores didn't come back after the server came up again.  I can see the server in /live_nodes.

But all is not bad: The data in the collection is volatile with a TTS of 30 minutes, and we have a failover in place that tries a new random compositeId whenever an "add" operation fails.

My question is: Is it possible to recreate the missing shards or do I have to delete and create the collection from scratch?

I know which hash ranges are are missing, but the [CREATESHARD](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api8) API call doesn't support shards with the 'compositeId' router.  And I cannot use [SPLITSHARD](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api3) since it only divides the original shard's hash.

<sub><sup>(We use Solr 5.4.0 and can't upgrade before 6.1 is released, ref. [SOLR-8940](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8940))</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

So, I [asked the same question](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201606.mbox/%3CCACEcJG4DJz2+ByeDr4QLCo2_tRqymUYsq0kJUGt7M9jYQanYUw@mail.gmail.com%3E) at the solr-user mailing list.  The [answer I got](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201606.mbox/%3CCAN4YXvfW7uf3oN=iff83rH2Pu+zE-b-S==T_dXidO+r-X-6tow@mail.gmail.com%3E) suggests using [zkNavigator](https://github.com/looprock/zkNavigator) and editing `state.json`, adding the missing shard(s) with the correct parameters.  An [ADDREPLICA](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api_addreplica) API call is needed afterwards.

I haven't gotten around to trying it yet, but I will do if the problem reoccurs.